# Displaying Multiple CALayers one after another continuously for 60 seconds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer

I have a situation over here.

I am using AVFoundation to capture the camera frame.
Now what i want to do is that for certain frames, i need to display a picture which revolves in a step by step fashion.

What I am trying to do is that I am taking 4 CALayers comprising of front back left and right images of an object and using CALayer time property and group animation property, i want to display all the images one by one after certain milli seconds interval of time so that the continuous images seems to be like an animation.

How to go about it ? Please help me with some coding here.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean? Do you want to display the video in a layer but step frame by frame or do you want to show different frames as still images in different layers? If you mean showing videos frame by frame, have you looked at `AVSynchronizedLayer`?

Comment: i have 3 CALayers and each having one image. I need to display these 3 calayers one by one one after the other in such a manner as if it is animated.

Comment: So you are almost talking about having one layer that changes its image for every frame of the movie? If so, you should read about `AVPlayer` and `AVSynchronizedLayer` in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSynchronizedLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The synchronized layer can display the content of your movie, you can even have multiple layers showing the same `AVPlayerItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)startMainAnimation
{
  //Animationframes is array of images that should be CGImage Type not UIImage..
  //animation Layer that is added above view……


  CAKeyframeAnimation *frameAnimation = [[CAKeyframeAnimation alloc] init];
  [frameAnimation setKeyPath:@"contents"];
  frameAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
  [animationLayer setContents:[animationFrames lastObject]];
  frameAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
  frameAnimation.duration = ((float)[animationFrames count])/4.5;;
  frameAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
  [frameAnimation setValues:animationFrames];
  [frameAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
  [frameAnimation setDelegate:self];
  [animationLayer addAnimation:frameAnimation forKey:@"contents"];
  [frameAnimation release];

}
```

Comment: You didn't even bother to paste the code in the answer? Still a nice trick to animate the `contents` of a layer but I think that the code would benefit from some explanation of how to use it and what values should go into the `animationFrames` array etc.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist the code is easy to study . It might be because i myself was trying out CAKeyFrameAnimation but wasnt able to figure out the structure in a Perfect Workable Manner

Comment: Please post the code in the answer. That site could go down, or the link could vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Answer on the basis of Mohit Gupta's pastie link:

**Set CALayer on which you want image sequence animation**

```
CALayer *animationLayer = [CALayer layer];
[animationLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 0, 240, 300)];
[self.baseLayer addSublayer:animationLayer];
```

**Define Array of Images needed to be shown in sequence animation**

```
NSArray *animationFrames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIImageimageNamed:@"1.png"].CGImage, (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"].CGImage, (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"].CGImage, nil];
```

**Using CAKeyframeAnimation to display array of images in sequential manner**

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *frameAnimation = [[CAKeyframeAnimation alloc] init];
[frameAnimation setKeyPath:@"contents"];
frameAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete; //mode of transformation of images
[animationLayer setContents:[animationFrames lastObject]]; //set the array objects as encounterd
frameAnimation.autoreverses = NO; //If set Yes, transition would be in fade in fade out manner
frameAnimation.duration = ((float)[animationFrames count])/4.5; //set image duration , it can be predefined float value
frameAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL; //this is for inifinite, can be set to any integer value as well
[frameAnimation setValues:animationFrames];
[frameAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
[frameAnimation setDelegate:self];
[animationLayer addAnimation:frameAnimation forKey:@"contents"]; //add animation to your CALayer
[frameAnimation release];
```

Hope this helps