# Animation of Images in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I am new in Windows Phone, and I've used `AnimationArray` in iOS to achieve the animation property of multiple images but I'm not sure how to accomplish the same in Windows Phone 8. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of images - use BitmapImage[] for that. Then, using a Timer with specified interval, change the Source property for a Image XAML element.

Comment: thanks a lot....I have one more question that can we use animation in core level.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? What do you mean by core level.

Comment: I mean as in iOS we can handle animation on layers of views,In the same way is there any way in WP.

Comment: please see it  I want just like that as in iOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214977/displaying-multiple-calayers-one-after-another-continuously-for-60-seconds/11219999#11219999 and please don't mind I post link of iPhone..

Comment: I am not familiar with iPhone development so I can't really compare what equivalent WP has for layers in iOS. You usually animate stuff via Storyboards and such, and layers do not exist in any meaningful way in XAML. Everything is declared in one file similar to HTML.